# Is there any way to initiate a class with itself?

Tags: c#, constructor, visual-studio-2015

Assume that, I have some decent class and want to initiate it from db. But I don't want to use any setter or something like copy constructor.

Do you know any better solution?

Let me explain it with example..

I have a User class - as you can see from the example - with a ctor, and have another ctor with a PK.
I want to find my user from db with that PK and userInside variable should be my new User object.

How to replace userInside with the base class itself?

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User()
    {

    }

    public User(int id)
    {
        var userInside = dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == id);

    }
}
```

Comment: set the properties to private and just fill them?

Comment: Well, what you probably want is an object factory. One way could be to change User(int) to CreateUser(id) and make it a static function.

Comment: Having a class that populates itself from a repository is not good practice - you add an unnecessary dependence on the repository and prevent unit testing.  Better to use a factory as @NickoPo suggests.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to do what you are asking to do. The syntax would be:

```
public User(int id)
{
    var userInside = dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == id);
    this = userInside;
}
```

However, you'll see that if you try that, you'll get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot assign to '<this>' because it is read-only.
```

Comment: Of course there are a multitude of ways to accomplish the end result of what you need to do, this is specifically answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

I usually add a static `FromId` function to the class that builds the instance for me for this purpose.

```
public static User FromId(int id)
{
    User u = new User();

    u......

    return u;

}
```

And use it like this.

```
User TheUser = User.FromId(45);
```

Answer (score 1):

[p e p's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33266757/80274) already covers why doing it in the constructor will not work, as an alternative one option you could do is use a static method on on the class to return a new instance.

```
public class User
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public User()
    {

    }

    public static User GetUser(int id)
    {
        return dataContext.Users.FirstOrDefault(q => q.ID == id);
    }
}
```

So the two ways you could call it would be

```
var foo = new User();
var bar = User.GetUser(0);
```